# Creating a higher order function to compare values

Tags: javascript, jquery, compare, higher-order-functions

So my assignment is to create a memory card game. We are required to use jQuery or JavaScript to flip the cards, compare them, then un-flip them.

So far I can get up to two cards to flip, but I can't get them to un-flip or test for an icon match yet.

I think I need to use a higher order function, but I don't know exactly how to write it (especially because I'm really hung up on comparing values to test if the cards match or not).

Here's my jQuery stuff so far:

```
var track = 0;

$('li').click (function(){
track++
if (track === 1){
  $(this).addClass('flipped')
  $(this).children().css('opacity', '1');
  console.log(track);
  }

  else if (track === 2){
  $(this).addClass('flipped')
  $(this).children().css('opacity', '1');
  console.log(track)
  }
});


$('li').click (function(){

    if ($(this).val() == ($(cardFlip).val ()){
    $(this).removeClass('flipped')
    $(this).addClass('permanent');
}
  else {
    $(this).removeClass('flipped');
    $(this).childre().css('opacity', '0');
  }
});
```

I have corresponding CSS classes that are 'flipped', 'permanent', and ones for the card's starting point and the icon.

JS Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/9b2038zx/

Comment: Some [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) demo would be good to help

Comment: why do you think a higher order function may help you? what would it help you with?

Answer (score 0):

You need only one click event to bind.

```
var track = 0;
var flippedExists = false;
var flipped;
$('li').click (function(){
    track++
    if (flippedExists){
         if ($(this).val() == flipped.val()){   //success
            $(this).removeClass('flipped')
            $(this).addClass('permanent');
            flipped.removeClass('flipped')
            flipped.addClass('permanent');
        }else {                                 //fail
            flipped.removeClass('flipped');
            flipped.children().css('opacity', '0');
        }
        flippedExists = false;
    }else{                                      //first flip
        flippedExists = true;
        flipped = $(this);
        $(this).addClass('flipped')
        $(this).children().css('opacity', '1');
    }
});
```